# Coroutines or Stateful/resumable tasks with Chaiscript

Tags: c++, chaiscript

I would like to use `Chaiscript` to let users of my application implement  tasks or stateful algorithms by using a scripting language. These algorithms  "depend on events during time". In other words, the algorithms, which are scheduled by the application, should be allowed to `yield` their execution at any time and to `resume` whenever an event they are interested in occurs (in which case the task is rescheduled for resumption). What kind of support does `Chaiscript` provide to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There has been various discussions surrounding the implementation of co-routines and similar, but nothing has been implemented yet.

See here: http://discourse.chaiscript.com/t/co-routines-in-chaiscript/33
And here: https://gitter.im/ChaiScript/ChaiScript?at=5557ceac076ab5646e6de3e8

Depending on your exact needs it might be possible to have your function return its own continuation. A pair of `(value, function_to_get_next_value)`, since chaiscript does easily support passing of function objects and lambda

Comment: @Martin Here's a possibility of a stateful function call implementation https://gist.github.com/lefticus/0358b6450cc994c71c70 with the discussion updated here http://discourse.chaiscript.com/t/co-routines-in-chaiscript/33/4